# react-router: How to configure layout component based on children?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router, redux

I have a Application global component and I'd like to configure it based on current path, like that:

```
function getComponentProps(path) {
  if (path === '/') return { className: 'bg-grey-200' }
  if (path === '/statistics')  return { title: 'Last views' }
  return {}
}

export default class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const config = getComponentProps(this.props.location.pathname)
    return {
      <div className={config.className}>
        {config.title && <h1>{config.title}</h1>}
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    }
  }
}

const routes = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route component={Application}>
        <Route path='/' component={Dasboard} />
        <Route path='statistics' component={Statistics} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)
```

Is that the correct way to do that? Or how you all are doing it? I know that I could make this on children component, but I'd like to be more DRY ;)

thanks for any help!

Comment: higher order components are always needed. Looks good to me. I think you mean `{config.title ? <h1>{config.title}</h1> : null}` though

Comment: thanks! you dont need to use ?: to make that works ;)

Comment: oops, I see that lol